# Default selection for <f:selectItem> within <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: jsf, default-value, selectonemenu

How to make default selection for `<f:selectItem>` within `<h:selectOneMenu>`?

It's needed,that particular "20" item of dropdown to be already selected when page is loaded.

```
  <h:selectOneMenu value="#{fileSearchCriteriaOut.recordsPerPage}"  >            
               <f:selectItem itemLabel="5" itemValue="5" />
               <f:selectItem itemLabel="10" itemValue="10" />
               <f:selectItem itemLabel="20" itemValue="20" selected="true"/>
  </h:selectOneMenu>
```

these four don't work:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="20" selected="true"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="20" selected="selected"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="20" checked="checked"/>
<f:selectItem itemLabel="20" checked="true"/>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="items" value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="10" itemValue="10"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="20" itemValue="20"/>
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="30" itemValue="30"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The default selection would be the one which has value same as `selectedItem` which you set in bean.

```
selectedItem = 20;
```

Comment: IMHO, I think you need an itemValue attribute in the selectItems?

Comment: look like I don't see your point) , I mentioned default selected combo item when .xhtml loaded

Comment: [There](http://myfaces.apache.org/core11/myfaces-impl/tlddoc/f/selectItem.html) is not such attribute, you need the reread what I have answered

Comment: In your Managed Bean you can set it as:

`setSelectedItem(String selectedItemId) { 
this.selectedItem = selectedItemId; 
}`

Answer (score 5):

Initialize the `recordsPerPage` in your backing bean.

From your source code I assume that you have a bean `FileSearchCriteriaOut` and your `recordsPerPage` is a `String`, then you can do the following in the bean's constructor:

```
public FileSearchCriteriaOut() {
   recordsPerPage = "20";
}
```

For the facelet refer to Jigar Joshi's answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="sexo"><span class="obligatorio">#{messageSource['etiqueta_requerido']}</span> #{messageSource['etiqueta_estatus']}
        </label>
        <p:selectOneRadio 
            id                  = "status"  
            required            = "true"
            requiredMessage     = "#{messageSource['mensaje_validacion_datoRequerido']}"
            value="#{mbUnidadDeMedida.dtoUnidadDeMedida.estatus}"
        >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messageSource['etiqueta_activo']}"   itemValue="1" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{messageSource['etiqueta_inactivo']}" itemValue="0" />
        </p:selectOneRadio>
    </div>
</div>
```