# default selected value in h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
            <h:selectOneMenu id="customerSelection" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter/Select a customer"
                value="#{engagement.selectedDropdownCustValue}" validator="#{engagement.validateCustomer}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Customer" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" itemDisabled="true" />
                <f:selectItems var="c" id="customer" itemLabel="#{c.name}" itemValue="#{c.name}" value="#{dashboard.customers}" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Other" itemValue="#{null}" />
                    <p:ajax update="engagementCustomer" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <p:inputText id="engagementCustomer" value="#{engagement.selectedEngagement.customer.name}"
                maxlength="30" disabled="#{engagement.selectedDropdownCustValue!=null}" validator="#{engagement.validateCustomer}" />
```

I want to have 'Select Customer' to be displayed in dropdown after page load, but Other is displayed by default in dropdown. Purpose of this code is to display already existing customers while creating new engagement, but if other value is selected from dropdown then input filed should be enabled and user should be allowed to enter new customer value.

Comment: Several things: Does it work if you replace `p:inputText` with an `h:inputText` and `p:ajax` with `f:ajax`? If not, it is not PrimeFaces related. And please post a [mcve], otherwise it is impossible to help

Comment: Yes tried using replacing p:inputText with h:inputText and p:ajax with f:ajax. It is not working for me.

Comment: Then I suggest to put that in the Q and remove the PF tag. Still make an [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default selection for <f:selectItem> within <h:selectOneMenu>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337101/default-selection-for-fselectitem-within-hselectonemenu)